# can somebody tell me why is this program not working?

Tags: python

Question: Create a function that returns the length of the string and returns error for integer and float data types.
The code is:

```
def string_length(mystring):
     if type(mystring) == int:
         return "Sorry, integers don't have length"
     elif type(mystring) == float:
         return "Sorry, floats don't have length"
     else:
         return len(mystring)

str=input("Enter the string: ")
print(string_length(str))
```

The output is:

```
PS E:\Software\Python\Programs> python .\myprogram.py
Enter the string: 23
2
PS E:\Software\Python\Programs> python .\myprogram.py
Enter the string: 45.3
4
PS E:\Software\Python\Programs>
PS E:\Software\Python\Programs> python .\myprogram.py
Enter the string: ashima
6
```

Can anyone tell me why is the output wrong?

Comment: `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: the `input` function will save all input as a string, therefore your `if` and `elif` statements never get run

Comment: You can test it working by calling it with a constant, like `string_length(78)`. Then it will be integer

Comment: Because == is matching string and int is a constant you have defined so try putting that in single quotes and then match the key strings and get the value and for the function you have created it's working fine because 23 is having length 2.

Comment: I get it. thankyou all

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
def string_length(mystring):
     if mystring.isdigit():
         return "Sorry, integers don't have length"
     elif mystring.isalpha():
         return len(mystring)
     else:
         return "Sorry, floats don't have length"

str=input("Enter the string: ")
print(string_length(str))
```

Comment: your code is working, And I got your point. Thank you